# splitting text for some bold and some not on functional javascript piece

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I currently have the following code

```
var temp = node.append("text")
.attr("dx", function(d) { return -8; })
.attr("dy", -4)
.style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.root ? "start" : "end"; })
.style("font-size", function(d) { return d.selected ? "16px" : "10px"; })
.style("font-weight", function(d) { return d.selected ? "bold" : ""; })
.text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

which is working fine.  This code receives a string however of form

```
streamname(module<-module<-module)
```

and if the json node contains a lastModuleSelected=true, I want the last module only in bold, not the whole thing and if lastModuleSelected=false, I want just the streamname to be in bold not the whole thing.

How can I go about doing this?  This is operating on many nodes of course so I am not sure how I would go about appending two text elements correctly since the string lengths vary in size....I still want one string but part of it bold and part of it normal.  Is there a way to do this?

NOTE: the d.root, d.selected and d.name are attributes in the received json and I will add a d.lastModuleSelected attribute as well.

I do have the option of separating out streamname and the module list as well if necessary if that makes it easier to write the javascript as well.  ie. instead of d.name, I might have d.streamname and d.moduleNameList as two separate attributes.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Is that [tag:d3.js]? Then please tag your question with it.

Comment: You would need to append several `tspan` elements to your `text` element to get bold and normal text, see http://www.svgbasics.com/font_effects_bold.html

Comment: That would make sense but I must have something just slight off.  Does this look right to you... var text = svg.selectAll(".node:text");
  text.append("tspan")
     .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.selected ? "16px" : "10px"; })
     .style("font-weight", function(d) { return d.selected ? "bold" : ""; })
     .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

Comment: ps. the above comment is just step 1 as I am trying to get this to work correctly and then can divide into better code, but tspan sounds like exactly what I want

Comment: I think I worked it out actually.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to @Lars Kotthoff and his comment, I was able to get this working as such

```
  var text = node.append("text")
  .attr("dx", function(d) { return -8; })
  .attr("dy", -4)
  .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.root ? "start" : "end"; });

 text.append("tspan")
 .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.selected && !d.isLastModule ? "16px" : "10px"; })
 .style("font-weight", function(d) { return d.selected && !d.isLastModule ? "bold" : ""; })
 .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

 text.append("tspan")
.style("font-size", function(d) { return d.selected && d.isLastModule ? "16px" : "10px"; })
.style("font-weight", function(d) { return d.selected && d.isLastModule ? "bold" : ""; })
.text(function(d) { return d.moduleList; });
```

Comment: This answer is a godsend.